# Fatal error when running Drush 4.4

Tags: drush

Do you have any idea on what might be causing this error in Drush w/ Drupal 7.2 (worked fine in Drupal 7.0)?

> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY' in /path/to/includes/database/mysql/database.inc on line 42
> Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                                                    [error]
> Error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY' in /path/to/includes/database/mysql/database.inc, line 42

Line 42 of database.inc contains the following line:

```
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => TRUE,
```

I thought this was related to PDO extension missing, but it is indeed installed.

This is the output of `drush -v -d status`.

> Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.03 sec, 1.28 MB]
> Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [0.03 sec, 1.41 MB]
> Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root() [0.07 sec, 3.18 MB]
> Initialized Drupal 7.2 root directory at /path/to [0.09 sec, 4.06 MB]
> Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [0.09 sec, 4.06 MB]
> Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [0.09 sec, 4.06 MB]   > Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [0.09 sec, 4.06 MB]
>
> Fatal error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY' in /path/to/includes/database/mysql/database.inc on line 42
> Drush command terminated abnormally due to an unrecoverable error.                                                                                                                     > Error: Undefined class constant 'MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY' in /path/to/includes/database/mysql/database.inc, line 42 [0.1 sec, 4.56 MB]

`phpinfo()` indicates that PDO and PDO MySQL are all installed. However, when I run `pecl remote-info pdo` (and `pdo-mysql`), I get * Installed - no -*.

So it appears that via the web requests, the extensions appear as installed, but not from the command line (same instance of PHP 5.3). Is there a way to tell PECL what `phpinfo()` already knows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, another one for the "learning experience" column:

I specified

```
DRUSH_PHP=/path/to/php
```

right before this line in drush wrapper script:

```
if [ ! -z "$DRUSH_PHP" ] ; then
```

Works now.

Thanks @kiamlaluno & @Berdir for your time and input. Hopefully this helps others.

KM

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple PHP versions installed, then...

Comment: Yeah @Berdir, found that out after I opened the wrapper script. It runs a check using "which php", which was still pointing to an older version of php. When I ran php -m and pecl I was using the current version. Thanks again! (-:

Answer (score 3):

You are most likely missing the pdo_mysql extension, which you also not, not only pdo and mysql/mysqli (that one is actually not necessary for *Drupal 7*, but is if you're also using Drupal 6 or other projects which use it).

You can see the enabled modules with:

```
php -m
```

Make sure it lists both PDO and PDO_mysql and if not, enable/install that.

Comment: Thanks @Berdir. I tried that and I get these: PDO,pdo_mysql,pdo_pgsql,pdo_sqlite. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue report on Drupal.org, [Fatal error in D7 HEAD while running 'drush update'](http://drupal.org/node/510912), where the OP reports a similar error.
One user reports the error can be fixed when the php_pdo_mysql extension is installed; another user reports it is necessary to install php5-mysql, under Ubuntu 10.10.